Converting a double product into a single product
Consider the product
$$
P=\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^k X_{ij}^{y_{ij}}(1-X_{ij})^{1-y_{ij}},
$$
where $y_{ij}=0\mbox{ or }1$ $\forall i$. I would like to convert this double product into a single index product. Any ideas? thanks.
